# RelativeLayout behaves different as list view item

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-relativelayout, xml-drawable

Good afternoon droids!

I am facing an annoying layout problem to which i have no explanation after hours and hours of investigation... :/. **I created a reduced test case which i present here.**

**I have a simple list item layout.**

[list item http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4075a.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4075a.jpg)

[lis item image link](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4075a)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="96dp">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="10dp" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:src="@drawable/errorindicator"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the errorindicator is a red rectangle, which you can see on the image on the left side. The xml looks like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape shape="rectangle"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="@color/ControllingConflictColor" />
     <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" 
         android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
    </shape>
```

**The described list item layout works as expected.**

Now i try to **fill a list view with list items** as described above. The result looks like that:

[list view with list items http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4cc4b.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4cc4b.jpg)

[list view image link](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4cc4b)

The corresponding xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/test -->
    </ListView>
```

**As you can see on the image, the red rectangle does not match it's parent in the height anymore as it should.** The images are made from the designer, but the same effect is also on the emulator and device. I am developing for API Level 8.

**I'd love if somebody could explain me, why the described layout does not work as expected in a list view. Why does the shape drawable behave different? **

Thank you for your time :)

edit: i have problems embedding the image, i used a link instead, sorry ;(
edit: added xml-drawable tag.

**edit:** My example can be even made much more easier. I included two text views because it has some similarity to my real layout. You can remove the two text views from the example and there still exists the problem, that the shape drawable in the image view does not match the parents height as defined, if the layout is used in a list view.

Comment: What is your desired layout design?

Comment: You need a line below of all textview right?

Comment: Venky you can see the desired design in the first linked image. The problem is, that the red shape drawable behaves different, if i use the described relative layout in a list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i guess my desired behaviour is not possible with the give layout manager, i went another way which fits my personal situation.

I have overriden the onDraw method of the RelativeLayout and paint this red rectangle myself (after the layout process finished and the heights are set)...

Answer (score 0):

Im also finding it hard to get it done using a RelativeLayout. Well try this layout for your row xml. It uses LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:id="@+id/textView2" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="10dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/errorindicator"/>       
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_weight="1.0" 
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:gravity="center"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer blessenm. The problem description is a reduced example to show that the shape drawable does not match the parents height, if i use the described relative layout in a list view. So the behaviour of the same layout is different, if used in a list view or not. I know there are different ways to achieve visually the same effect as in my example, but the layout is much more simpler and performant as relative layout. The question is more, why does the shape drawable behave different. I guess there must be something differing in the layout process of list views...

Comment: I did notice that when the size was specified for the shape drawable, it showed up. Might try it out later and see whats wrong as it seems strange to me too.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please notice that i edited my question and pointed out, that the text views are not relevant.

Comment: I found out now that, if the relative layout has a fixed android:layout_height, then the image view fills the parents height. But in my case i'd prefer to have a fixed value (preferred height) as minHeight but the row should be able to grow more than that in the height... hmmm :/

Comment: I guess my desired behaviour is just not possible.
RelativeLayout documentation says:
"Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM. "

So my RelativeLayout with its height set to wrap content and it's children to with its height set to match_parent is such a circular dependency!?

But if the RelativeLayout would first calculate it's height through child with a specific height it could work...

Answer (score 0):

If you made the asset as a png, you could then 9-patch it and add it as the background of the RelativeLayout

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I did not try it out, but i can imagine that would also work as workaround (even without 9-patch and with the existing shape drawable). But it still does not answer my question ;(